# How to match rows values in a DataFrame to a value in another DataFrame

Tags: pandas

[image]

What I want to do is to create a new table which contains all the data in **Table 1** with additional one column named **Description** (value from **Table 2**) which should match the **Part Number** in **Table 1**.

I have tried use `df.merge` however, it just makes `Table 3` more than three rows.

I have also tried `lookup` but with no success.
[image]

The code I used to produce image above,

```
pd.merge(xl_csv, xl_df, on="Part Number", how="left")[['Part Number', 'Occurrence Count', 'G1 TAT_x', 'Description']]
```

Comment: I don't know what are the indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems need left join and then select columns by subset, but first need remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) in `df2`:

```
cols = ['Part Num','Sample','Description']
df = pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates('Part Num'), on='Part Num', how='left')[cols]
print (df)
   Part Num Sample  Description
0         1    one    Desc. one
1         2    two    Desc. two
2         3  three  Desc. three
```

Another solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['Description'] = df1['Part Num'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('Part Num')
                                            .set_index('Part Num')['Description'])
print (df1)
   Part Num Sample  Description
0         1    one    Desc. one
1         2    two    Desc. two
2         3  three  Desc. three
```

Comment: Table 2 actually has more than two columns but I just want **Description**.

Comment: See my update, the `merge` expands the **Part Number** into multiple rows.

Comment: Yes, there is problem you have duplicates. So need firs remove them.

Comment: Looks like a solid answer to me :-)  Good night!

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: @piRSquared - Good night too ;)